# Проверка есть ли данные в строке бд

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Подскажите пожалуйста, пытаюсь сделать условие, если есть какие то данные в указанном поле то обновить их, а если нет добавить, update и insert прописал, а вот как сделать условие? C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно парой update/insert с проверкой `@@rowcount`:

```
update [table]
set column = @value
where id = @id;

if @@rowcount = 0
    insert into [table] (id, column)
    values (@id, @value);
```

Либо `merge`:

```
merge into [table] t
using (select @id, @value) s (id, column)
on t.id = s.id
when matched then
    update
        set t.column = s.column
when not matched then
    insert (id, column)
    values (s.id, s.column);
```

Да, и соответственно в C# коде что-то наподобие:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "..."; //тут один из двух SQL запросов, что выше

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", "какое-то значение");

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT [field] FROM [table]
              WHERE [field] = @oldValue)
BEGIN
   INSERT [table]
   (
      [field]
   )
   VALUES
   (
      @newValue,
   )
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   UPDATE [table]
   SET [field] = @newValue
   WHERE [field] = @oldValue
END
```

В С# достаточно будет создать объект SqlCommand с этим запросом, передав в него два параметра:

- @oldValue - значение которое нужно обновить, если оно есть в базе
- @newValue - новое значение